# Preventing or blocking cpu data cache loading

Tags: c++, c, arm, benchmarking, cpu-cache

I'm tasked with evaluating various flavors of ARM processors (benchmarking), specifically System On a Chip (SOC).  Some SOC's have a lot of data cache, others have little.  Because of this, I'd like my program to block the data cache.

I have written a Walking 1 test which accesses memory outside the core, but on the SOC.  I'm going to run this on our present processor, that has very little data cache, and run it on a Cortex M3 processor, which has a lot of data cache memory.

I'm focusing on durations to fetch memory outside the processor.  If I set the size of memory for the Walking 1 to a size larger than the data cache, the to run the test "exponentiates" in time.  For example, for a small size of memory, the test runs in minutes, for larger memory sizes, the test takes hours.

**Question:  Is there an idiom that can be used to prevent the processor from loading the entire array into the processor's data cache?**
*(Note:  This is tagged as C and C++ because I have the option to choose between the languages.  If C has no idiom, but C++ does, than I will try C++ first.)*

- Platform:  Various embedded or System On a Chip (development /
  evaluation boards), no OS.
- Processor: ARM Cortex series with different peripherals on the chip
  and different data cache sizes.
- Compilers: IAR Embedded Workbench, GNU C, GNU C++ (used in the
  background by various board suppliers).

Comment: If you are focusing on memory bandwidth, then [What is the fastest way to copy memory on a Cortex-A8?](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html) maybe helpful.  As a matter of fact, selectively disabling the cache maybe unfair.  Some memory (DDR SDRAM) is very good at writing larger amounts (8*16bits for example).  If you force smaller sizes, you can make memory transfers in-efficient.  Ie, some memory types work better with cache, so it can be un-fair to disable them.  I would at least test different sizes of read/writes with the cache disabled.

Comment: Is your "present processor" also M-class, or one of the older architectures? Be aware that the M3 and friends don't have architected caches, so any control of external caches may well be SoC-specific, and in general rather different to A-class/legacy architectures (e.g. memory-mapped system registers instead of CP15)

Comment: I think you need to re-read the arm docs on what arch has what, second if you dont want to use the data cache then simply dont turn it on...also understand the nature of each chip you are using with respect to the geometry and speed of the rams you are talking to

Comment: @artlessnoise:  I'm trying to make a fair benchmark between our present ARM7TDMI and some Cortex versions. I want to show management the performance benefits by upgrading.

Comment: @Notlikethat: Our present processor is NXP79525, an SOC containing an ARM7TDMI.  We are processing data samples and want more bandwidth, thus the comparisons to all the Cortex's.  Maybe the data cache should be enabled as part of the benchmarking, still not sure.

Comment: Unless your application code accesses memory entirely at random, then cache is liable to be a significant factor in your choice rather than a variable to try to remove, given its ability to hide memory latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your compiler provides functions to access the memory region protection registers, you'll need to do some assembly to set memory region(s) to non-cacheable:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0290g/Chdhdahb.html

or as mentioned below globally disable level one data and instruction cache via bits 2 and 12 of the c1 control register, which is accessed via co-processor register 15 = CP 15:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0338g/Babebdcb.html

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0338g/Babgdhif.html

This assumes that your ARM processors have CP 15 functionality. There may be other control registers that might be useful for your tests. I'm not sure how this would be done on ARM processors without CP 15 functionality.

Comment: An MPU is optional on a Cortex-M3 chip.  Other ARM CPU's may have an MMU and on both, a bare metal application may not use either.  However, you are correct that marking a section/region as non-cacheable is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't to what @rcglfr said, you could iterate through the data by the size of a cache line.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid to modify your MMU tables, you may just disable your data cache (and your L2 cache if you have 1).

On ARM926EJ-S, this is done as follow :

```
// Enable the data cache
FUNC_START_ARM(hal_dcache_enable,r1)
    push    {lr}
    mov     r0,#0
    mcr     p15,0,r0,c7,c6,0            /* invalidate d-cache */
    mrc     p15,0,r1,c1,c0,0
    orr     r1,r1,#0xC
    /* enable DCache and write buffer */
    mcr     p15,0,r1,c1,c0,0
    pop     {lr}
    bx      lr

// Disable the data cache (and invalidate it, required semantics)
FUNC_START_ARM(hal_dcache_disable,r1)
    push    {lr}
1:  mrc     p15,0,r15,c7,c14,3
    bne     1b
    mrc     p15,0,r1,c1,c0,0
    bic     r1,r1,#0xC
    /* disable DCache AND write buffer  */
    mcr     p15,0,r1,c1,c0,0
    mov     r1,#0
    mcr     p15,0,r1,c7,c6,0    /* clear data cache */
    pop     {lr}
    bx      lr
```

Just look in the ARM Architecture reference manual to know how to disable d-cache on your ARM.

Be sure to follow ARM guidelines about cache invalidation when you enable/disable cache (it depends on your ARM core)

Answer (score 0):

After talking with coworkers, we would be keeping the data and instruction caches on.

The evaluation is for performance improvement between the Cortex family and our ARM7TDMI processor.  A large part of the improvement are the caches.

In summary, to disable caches, assembly language must be used.  There is no high level language idiom to prevent the CPU from using the cache.  CPUs are designed to make the best use of the data and instruction caches.